# How to read sms box from PWA application

Tags: vue.js, sms, progressive-web-apps

I am using `vuejs`. Can I read SMS from `PWA app`? Is it possible?
(I don't mean OTP, I want if some SMS received, for example from bank, I update wallet)

Comment: Nope. No can do.